# How to get duration of .webm audio file using getID3?

Tags: php, laravel, webm, getid3

I'm building a Laravel application where we need to store user-submitted recordings as well as some metadata such as duration. [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997077/getid3-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43949752/13593058) have suggested using `playtime_seconds` or `playtime_string` but neither of these keys exist for me when I call the `analyze()` function on the file, despite getID3 supposedly fully supporting the `webm` format:

[image]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: the below is what the `analyze()` method returns. Note the `error` and `warning` fields:

[image]

Comment: Works ok for me, using `composer require james-heinrich/getid3` and samples from [here](https://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/).

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for the comment! Yes, the sample file works, but any other .webm doesn't, as the `analyze()` function returns quite different results. There are also values for `warning` and `error` (see my post update). This makes it seem like the .webm files are faulty but I'm not sure what could be wrong with them as playing them back does not lead to any issues.